# HTML markup templates in PHP

Tags: php, html, templates, template-engine

When I write PHP code for websites, I don't like mixing business logic with the presentation layer and as such I tend to create markup templates. I've written a very lightweight template engine to facilitate this, since I really don't want to move to a fully-fledged template framework like Smarty.

Here's a simplified example of what I do:

```
function renderTemplatePage($page, $params)
{
    $page = readTemplateFile("templates/{$page}");
    $tokens = getTemplateTokens($page);
    foreach($tokens as $token)
    {
        if(substr($token, 0, 6) == "%_TPL_")
        {
            $subPage = renderTemplatePage(tokenToPageName($token), $params);
            $page = str_replace($token, $subPage, $page);
        }
        else
        {
            $page = str_replace($token, $params[$token], $page);
        }
    }
    return $page;
}
```

Sample page:

```
<html>
    <head><title>%_PageTitle_%</title></head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">%_TPL_Header_%</div>
        <div id="content">%_TPL_Homepage_%</div>
        <div id="footer">%_TPL_Footer_%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

A call to `renderTemplatePage("index", array("PageTitle" => "Home"))` would produce a page entitled "Home", with content from the Header, Homepage and Footer templates.

I do all of my logic (including db queries, etc) before calling the rendering, so I can mass up a large `$params` array and just do a single call to render it all.

Are there any flaws in this methodology? Is there a more standard way to do this?

Comment: There are *many* template engines readily available in PHP. There is usually little sense in creating your own, but if it suits your needs, great. This is not really a question...

Comment: You could get a ready template system, such as smarty. It would be easier for others to follow.

Comment: @anttir - As I said, I don't want to use Smarty or any other fully fledged template engine.

Comment: @draevor - I'm not asking for suggestions for replacement engines. I just want to know if there are any flaws in how I'm defining templates and having my engine read them. Usually there's a "best practice" rule for things like this.

Comment: And thus a long discussion would start. If the str_replace works, that's great, besides that you might be interested in html escaping and lots of other topics that a template engine does or can do. "Fully-fledged" does not exist and there are lots of "light" engines available.

Comment: I am curious, what is `%_TPL_Homepage_%` content?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel - If you look at the code, you'll see that the `%_TPL_` prefix causes the appropriate template to be injected, in this case the `Homepage` template. It passes the same `$params` into the template renderer. In reality there's some more logic that goes into this, e.g. having different parameters for repeated use of the same template. This gives the result of a single `renderTemplatePage` call that produces all the necessary markup.

Comment: I don't want to look in the code  I want to look in the template thanks

Comment: The code is what *handles* the templates. Essentially `%_TPL_` is an include to another template. As I said, it's a simplified version of what I really do. Including the same template twice doesn't neccessarily result in the same markup twice.

Comment: Mustache is a very simple templating system similar to this, worth a look for ideas/inspiration https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

Comment: -1 for asking "oversimplified" question, actually concealing many important parts.

Comment: I was only concealing the crud. I was mainly interested in whether find/replace style templates are considered "ok", or if there's a method considered much more "standard" by a higher majority.

Comment: implementing logic is somewhat different from simple "find/replace". you have to make your mind first and then ask a complete question. But to answer your latter question - no, "find/replace style templates" aren't ok, as they're insufficient for the real world tasks. BTW, setting css classes in the business logic is breaking the whole idea of separation as well. Is designer supposed to go into code?

Comment: The CSS classes are simply set by parameter. `class="%_ShowWhatever_%"` is perfectly acceptable by my standards, as long as I'm not actually writing CSS or HTML markup in with my logic code.

Comment: so, you are having class names in your code, not template. that's what I am talking about.

Comment: Yes. Nothing wrong with that. I could easily modify it to remove that requirement though, like `%_Var_?{% <!-- code conditional on var=1 here --> %}?%`.

Comment: CSS definitely belongs to presentation layer. And you are mixing it with business logic - the thing you wanted to get rid of. You have to make your mind first. Otherwise not a single soul be able to help you. If you have your conditions implemented - then you have posted not the real code. I see no point in such an action.

Comment: Yes, CSS _itself_ belongs to the presentation layer. The class names are hardly important. And, as I said, I could easily circumvent that with conditional markup. Anyway, I've expressed what I'm concerned with and what I'm not concerned with. If you have something to add that is helpful in answering the parts that I **am** concerned with, feel free. If all you have to say is related to the parts that I **am not** concerned with, you're going off topic and I'm really not interested. Otherwise this conversation is just going to end up being a form of gratification for your argumentative streak.

Comment: How come class names are hardly important? Someone have to define them in the CSS file. Suppose it's poor designer. How it is supposed for him to use these classes in the actual template? By editing the code?

Comment: Yes. That *someone* is me. I'm not writing this as an extensive framework for multi-developer groups. If I wanted that, I'd have gone for Smarty. Now, if you're finished blatantly ignoring me... :/

Comment: Well, I still have many important issues out of my experience to share, but if it's your strong desire - so be it.

Comment: OK folks - let's agree to differ, and move on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its flawed. How do you handle template specific logic . Just out of curiosity how would you handle `ifs` or `loops`

Comment: The demonstration I gave above is very simplified. I'm using `%{%` and `%}%` to express loops, where each internal variable index is incremented across iterations. The conditional stuff is partly handled by having small injected templates that get selected dynamically (`%_TPL?_Var_%` inserts template `$params['Var']`), and also by changing markup visibility with CSS.

Comment: I'll accept this because it made me think more about how I'm handling my conditional includes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of achieving separation between logic and representation (it's formally known as part of MVC - Model-View-Controller methodology).

One direction I would like to point you in is XML+XSLT. The idea is to assemble all the information you need as an XML string (e.g. have a look at the output of the following URL: http://www.whiteoctober.co.uk/?dumpXML) , and then perform an XSLT transform on it (see http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp).

Templating in PHP is a religious debate - one I would rather not get dragged into. Suffice to say I'm strongly against Smarty - it's bulky and does nothing that standard PHP does not already do.

Comment: I've got a little experience with XML/XSLT, but don't really want to have to entirely transition into it. I'd be *much* more comfortable working directly with HTML markup. And very much agreed on the Smarty front - I don't see the point in having a large bulky framework for this kind of thing.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with all these homebrew templates is lack of real life testing.
Instead of doing such a test you are coming here to ask other people.
It is not so wise strategy in general, as your own experience is indispensable, while there are not so much pro's hangs around having enough time to write you an extended answer. While there are always lots of inexperienced users ready to answer.

> Are there any flaws in this methodology?

yes, of course.

You are declaring that you `don't like mixing business logic with the presentation layer`.
But whati is the content of `%_TPL_` and where it written? In the same old business logic, I suppose. So, where is your desired separation then?

Comment: Clearly you didn't wait for my response to your comment, or read the code properly. `%_TPL_` signifies an injected template, which is passed the same `$params` variable. All my business logic is done at the top of my code, then I end it with a single `renderTemplatePage` call that recursively renders all the sub-templates based on the params I handed it.

Comment: What are you talking about? Let's say the `Homepage.tpl` file has the following: `<h1>Homepage</h1><p>%_Message_%</p>`, and `$params` is `array("PageTitle" => "Home", "Message" => "Hello, world!")`, you'll get this: http://pastebin.com/TdDWVAMG

Comment: nay, I mean **real**, not helloworld one. say, a simple guestbook messages or news title page.

Comment: Why does it matter? The result is the same. If it *does* matter and I've not grasped why, please make your point clearly rather than being obtuse and trying to make me jump through hoops.

Comment: Just try it. And you'll see :)

Comment: Considering I already have a few pages working, I don't see your point. Quit being pedantic and make your point.

Comment: Considering you already have a few pages working, I am waiting for one. It is always better to discuss some real matter rather one imaginable one.

Comment: This discussion is unconstructive. You're clearly being awkward for the sake of it. If you've got something to say, then *say it*. Otherwise, don't bother.

Comment: This is 2-way road. One who asks have to be constructive as well as one who answers.